# How to identify minimum squared value of an entire pandas dataframe column by column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
column1 | column2  | column3
1       | 4        |   10.4  
4       | 7        |   11.1
3       | 3        |   3.3
```

How could I calculate the sum of the squared values for the entire column (I am trying something like `deviation = df[columnName].pow(2).sum()` in a loop, but ideas are very welcome!) but also afterwards identifying the column that has the smallest of those sums and the actual smallest sum?

Edit: Adding desired output

Desired output in this case would be:

```
Minimum sum of squared values: 26
Column containing minimum sum of squared values: column1
```

Comment: Please share the ideal output in the above scenerio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the sum of square on the entire data frame, which returns a Series object with the column names as index. And then you can find the minimum value as well as minimum index using `min` and `idxmin`:

```
col_squares = df.pow(2).sum()

col_squares
#column1     26.00
#column2     74.00
#column3    242.26
#dtype: float64

col_squares.min(), col_squares.idxmin()
#(26.0, 'column1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier/Understandable way to get the same result is as below

```
def minimum_square_sum_col(col):
    sums = 0
    for i in col:
        sums += i**2
    return sums
col_to_sum_dict = dict(df.apply(minimum_square_sum_col))
print(col_to_sum_dict)
```